# Is it normal that CPU % is about "what can be done" instead of "what is happening"?

Tags: c++, performance, cpu-usage

I have this function, which is called heavily within my application:

```
void Envelope::Process(Voice &voice) {
    VoiceParameters &voiceParameters = mVoiceParameters[voice.mIndex];

    // control rate
    if (voiceParameters.mControlRateIndex-- == 0) {
        voiceParameters.mControlRateIndex = PLUG_CONTROL_RATE - 1;

        DBGMSG("I'm entered");
    }

    // next phase
    voiceParameters.mBlockStep += mRate;
    voiceParameters.mStep += mRate;
}
```

This function never enter within the `if` statement (i.e. I never see that "I'm entered" message). And it takes 3% of CPU.

Now, if I write this function:

```
void Envelope::Process(Voice &voice) {
    VoiceParameters &voiceParameters = mVoiceParameters[voice.mIndex];

    // control rate
    if (voiceParameters.mControlRateIndex-- == 0) {
        voiceParameters.mControlRateIndex = PLUG_CONTROL_RATE - 1;

        DBGMSG("I'm entered");

        // samples (as rest) between two "quantized by block" sections occurs in the prev or next section, by round (interpolation). latest samples will be ignored (>) or added (<)
        if (mIsEnabled) {
            // update value
            voiceParameters.mValue = (voiceParameters.mBlockStartAmp + (voiceParameters.mBlockStep * voiceParameters.mBlockFraction));

            // scale value
            if (!mIsBipolar) {
                voiceParameters.mValue = (voiceParameters.mValue + 1.0) / 2.0;
            }
            voiceParameters.mValue *= mAmount;
        }
        else {
            voiceParameters.mValue = 0.0;
        }

        // connectors
        mOutputConnector_CV.mPolyValue[voice.mIndex] = voiceParameters.mValue;
    }

    // next phase
    voiceParameters.mBlockStep += mRate;
    voiceParameters.mStep += mRate;
}
```

(which does the same, since the code inserted will never be executed) the CPU raise 7%.

What's happening? How can it be?

I'm working in Release (or Tracer, nothing is different) modes.

Comment: Does `DBGMSG` do anything when compiled in release mode (i.e., are you sure the if-branch is never called)? If it is indeed never called, performance might be influenced by the length of the branch (that is very compiler/machine dependent, though).

Comment: It isn't very clear what kind of toolchain you use, "3% of CPU" and "Tracer" just don't mean much without that info.  Assuming you used a profiler, seeing functions with larger function bodies take more time is not unusual.  Even if code doesn't execute, optimizations like loop unrolling and inlining no longer apply.  Also, measurements on code that takes at most a handful of nanoseconds don't generally repeat very well.

Comment: The info is taken from the Host which is running it (Im within a DLL).

Comment: @chtz: Yes it print message to the output. Output that I never see. So it never reaches that code. What do you mean by "lenght of the branch"?

Answer (score 1):

Since the "unused" extra code contains a read of `voiceParameters.mBlockStep`, the writes to it become relevant. Compilers can take more liberty with write-only variables, potentially even eliminating them. But the least they can do is reorder such writes.

Comment: So what are you suggesting? Local variable?

Comment: @paizza: Not suggesting anything, just explaining why code that's not actually executing can restrict the optimizations of code elsewhere. If that not-executing code is indeed irrelevant, I'd prove that and remove it.

Comment: In this case I want to optimize code. I mean: that not used code is relevant, and will be executed once every tot time (control rate: once every second for example). Saying this, the rest of code must take 3% of CPU, not 7. How can you suggest?